# Область видимости функций внутри одного листинга

Tags: python, python-3.x

Уважаемые коллеги, приветствую!

В основном пишу на PHP и JavaScript, но хочу уметь и Python. И вот в какой-то момент для меня неочевидным оказалось поведение вызова функции до ее объявления. Т.е., если python выдает ошибку NameError для следующего кода:

```
get_name()
def get_name(name='John'):
    print('Hello, ', name)
```

то в аналогичной ситуации PHP и JS отрабатывают без ошибок и выдают ожидаемый мной результат. С классами тоже самое. Если оформить отдельным модулем и импортировать вначале файла, то все работает. Но в том-то и дело, что мне не всегда нужно несколько файлов, а всего один. И поэтому получается какая-то неорганизованная мешанина из определений функций и их вызовов, не получается организовать логическую структуру, внутренний перфекционист страдает... Это как-нибудь решается в пределах одного файла? Я понимаю, что выполнение кода происходит по мере его интерпретации, но PHP и JS как-то ж работают. Или это из-за их JIT`а? Но ведь и python сохраняет промежуточный вариант в виде байт-кода. Или я что-то не так понимаю? Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Функции вверху, вызовы внизу. Не вижу в этом какой-либо мешанины

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но он не объясняет причину такого поведения python. Если знаете, подскажите. Я привык и мне нравится, когда все функции сгруппированы внизу. Мне кажется удобным, когда открываешь файл и сразу видишь, какую задачу решает код, а не определение функции -> ее вызов -> определение функции -> ее вызов... Может, есть какие-то параметры командной строки вызова интерпретатора для прекомпиляции, в рез. которой в байт-коде будет что-то вроде глобальных флагов на эти функции для возможности вызова их из любого участка кода?

Comment: Это невозможно, так как объявление функции может зависеть от переменных, объявленных выше по коду (например что-то вроде `def foo(args=a)` когда переменная `a` объявлена выше, или создание функции в зависимости от условия `if something: def foo():...`)

Comment: Если вы хотите видеть задачу вверху, вы всегда можете описать её в функции вверху и вызвать эту функцию внизу https://pastebin.com/3wMkUnuY

Comment: Функция main() - хороший вариант и позволяет структурировать код лучше, спасибо! Может вы знаете, почему PHP и JS могут работать без такого хака?

Comment: Ну вообще это зависит от реализации интерпретатора языка. Но так то Python интерпретируемый язык, поэтому нормально, что он код воспринимает последовательно по мере того, как его видит.

Comment: @CrazyElf, так PHP и JS тоже интерпретируемы. Что у них есть такого, чего нету в Python`е в данном вопросе?